# Android Firebase Database Add Object To List

Tags: android, list, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of comment objects inside of an object. If I want to add a comment without touching the other comments how would I do that? I have used transactions in the past for editing an integer efficiently but I don't know if I can do that with a list. The end goal is for multiple users to be a ble to add comments at the same time without cutting eachother off (overriding their edits).

Here is an example of my database:
[image]

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sort_data

Answer (score 3):

Solved it! Super simple. Just had to add push() to the end of my DatabaseRefercence like so. It gives every comment a key.

```
commentRef = pollRef.child("comments").push();
commentRef.setValue(comment);
```